# Writing Phrases with Code

Tags: popularity-contest, source-layout

This is my first contest, so please tell me what I can do to improve.

The object of this contest is to write program lines in your language of choice that are both valid code and self-descriptive in English, such as this Golfscript program:

```
This program outputs 4 twice.
```

You may use any language features, libraries, #defines, etc. that you want; however, a setup must not be over 10 lines (no, you can't cheat using ; or any such line separator :P).

The program with the most upvotes by midnight on October 1st wins.

Comment: I'd say you may want to reword 'Must not be over 10 lines' since technically a full-blown program can be on one continuous line. Maybe adding a character restriction per line or overall character limit.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure what the line limit is going to accomplish. As a fellow GolfScriptling, you know hat some languages aren't even organized by lines. 2. Self-descriptive code is the exact opposite of obfuscation. 3. The *code-challenge* tag is only for questions that are not covered by *code-golf*, *popularity-contest*, etc.

Comment: is [any language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare_%28programming_language%29) allowed?

Comment: This was a bad idea from the start, I'll admit. I just wanted to do something like the "aphorism" challenge, but I didn't want a duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

### Python

```
# This "program" does nothing and assumes "valid code" means it doesn't throw an error.
```

You *might* want to tighten up the rules a bit.

Answer (score 2):

## C

This was too easy...

```
#define This int
#define program main(){
#define prints printf(
#define and );
#define exits }

This program prints "Hello world!" and exits
```

### [English](http://esolangs.org/wiki/English)

```
This program outputs 99 verses in the manner:
"N bottles of beer on the wall
N bottles of beer
Take one down and pass it around
N-1 bottles of beer on the wall",
where N is replaced by numbers from 99 to 1
and 1-1=0 is replaced by "No more".
After that there is hundredth verse:
"No more bottles of beer on the wall
No more bottles of beer
Go to the store and buy some more
99 bottles of beer on the wall".
```

Answer (score 1):

## OS X say

```
say whatever you want man!
```